# Generate counts for the occurrence of each column but with respect to another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
   Machine |    Date   | ticket | Heavy | Med | Low |  
    Mach_1    1/2/1992    abb       1      0     0    
    Mach_1    1/6/1992    abb       1      0     1     
    Mach_1    1/6/1992    att       0      0     1     
    Mach_2    1/2/1992    avm       1      0     0     
    Mach_2    1/14/1992   avm       1      0     0   
    Mach_2    1/2/1992    avm       1      0     0
```

I want to generate a new table with the occurrence counts of the features of each machine but only the machines with the same name, same date but different ticket code.

So that it can generate a new DataFrame like this:

```
   Machine |    Date    | Heavy | Med | Low |  
    Mach_1    1/2/1992      1      0     0    
    Mach_1    1/6/1992      1      0     2        
    Mach_2    1/2/1992      1      0     0     
    Mach_2    1/14/1992     1      0     0   
    Mach_2    1/2/1992      1      0     0
```

ex: `Mach_1` on `1/6/1992` would have a `Heavy` count of `1` because it only appeared once on that date but had a count of `2` for `Low` because it appeared twice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `duplicated` + `groupby`.  This is a trickier problem because you want to keep duplicate rows, you just don't want to `sum` them.  The solution is ensuring that every duplicated row is assigned a new `id` using `cumsum`, and then using that key in our grouping.

---

```
d = df.duplicated(['Machine', 'Date', 'ticket'])
never_group = d.groupby(d).cumsum()

df.groupby(['Machine', 'Date', never_group], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

```
  Machine       Date  Heavy  Med  Low
0  Mach_1   1/2/1992      1    0    0
1  Mach_1   1/6/1992      1    0    2
2  Mach_2   1/2/1992      1    0    0
3  Mach_2  1/14/1992      1    0    0
4  Mach_2   1/2/1992      1    0    0
```

---

***Explanation***

Finding the duplicate values helps us generate our groups.

```
>>> d = df.duplicated(['Machine', 'Date', 'ticket'])
>>> d
0    False  
1    False  
2    False  
3    False  
4    False  
5     True  
dtype: bool
```

Next we have to ensure that all duplicated values are assigned a unique key

```
>>> d.groupby(d).cumsum().view('i1')
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
dtype: int8
```

This ensures that even if a value is duplicated more than once, it will remain in the final result as a unique row, but will not be aggregated, lets say your DataFrame looked like this:

```
  Machine       Date ticket  Heavy  Med  Low
0  Mach_1   1/2/1992    abb      1    0    0
1  Mach_1   1/6/1992    abb      1    0    1
2  Mach_1   1/6/1992    att      0    0    1
3  Mach_2   1/2/1992    avm      1    0    0
4  Mach_2  1/14/1992    avm      1    0    0
5  Mach_2   1/2/1992    avm      1    0    0
6  Mach_2   1/2/1992    avm      1    0    0
```

We have *three* duplicated values that need to be kept separated

```
>>> d = df.duplicated(['Machine', 'Date', 'ticket'])
>>> d.groupby(d).cumsum()
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
6    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop duplicates first, then `groupby` and sum()

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Machine', 'Date', 'ticket']).groupby(['Machine', 'Date']).sum()
```

---

```
                   Heavy  Med  Low
Machine Date                      
Mach_1  1/2/1992       1    0    0
        1/6/1992       1    0    2
Mach_2  1/14/1992      1    0    0
        1/2/1992       1    0    0
```